# Why statements after while loop is getting executed?

Tags: c#, azure, while-loop

I am working with Azure storage. 
Moving a file to secondary storage once it is available in primary storage, and the file is usually available in 3-5 seconds. I can see that it got moved to secondary storage, but the while loop kept getting executed until it got killed during nightly deployment after getting executed 7000 times.

```
public async Task<File> ProcessArchive()
{
    CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer
                        .GetBlockBlobReference(video);


    bool exists = sourceBlob.Exists();


    while (!exists)
    {
        await _logServices.Log(
            "Condition Triggered",
            "ProcessArchive",
            new
            {
                ArchiveId = archiveId
            });
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        exists = sourceBlob.Exists();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Moving operation code!");

}
```

Isn't it suppose to wait until while loop returns false and then execute the last line?

Update: While loop is still broken, now only difference is it is getting killed after 2 minutes after updated code.

```
            CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(video);

            bool exists = await sourceBlob.ExistsAsync();

            // Emergency bail-out
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

            while (!exists)
            {
                await _logServices.Log(
                    LogCategory.Audit,
                    "Condition Triggered",
                    "ProcessArchive",
                    new
                    {
                        ArchiveId = archiveId
                    });
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                sourceBlob = sourceContainer
                    .GetBlockBlobReference(video);
                exists = await sourceBlob.ExistsAsync();
                if (source.IsCancellationRequested) break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Rest of the code which is another 50 lines.");
```

Update: Jeez! We have some users trying to move already moved file!

Comment: To be clear, the message "Condition Triggered [...]" was logged 7000 times?

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep` in async code. Use `await Task.Delay(2000)` instead.

Comment: Yes, it gets logged every 2 seconds.

Comment: I'm not experienced in azure, but it seems as if `sourceBlob` doesn't realize when the existence of itself changes, so you probable have to call `sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(video);` in your while loop.

Comment: Also, [ExistsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.existsasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_ExistsAsync) may be better suited. I also recommend to include an emergency bail-out. For example add a counter that count each try and have the function fail if the counter reaches 10 (or whatever reasonable).

Comment: @Fildor will this work instead of timer? CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)); while (!exists || source.IsCancellationRequested) {........}

Comment: Probably. Only that it is time-based. I would have gone for a "you can retry x times, then give up". It's just to avoid running it forever.

Comment: Thanks all I made necessary changes. Replaced Thread.sleep with await Task.Delay(2000). added sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(video); inside while loop and added an emergency bail-out. I am still having hard time understanding async/await tasks.